# How can i call a functions.php function, from inside my plugin class?

Tags: plugins, functions

I have a function get_finance() inside my functions.php file. It is used site wide and I don't want to move it.

In my plugin, I can call all the other functions inside my class or other included classes.
$this->call_this_function();
But I get a fatal error when I call
$finance = get_finance();

I'm assuming this is because my plugin code is getting processed before functions.php is getting included?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When and how are you calling `$finance = get_finance();` in the class? When and how are you instantiating the class?

Comment: In my default plugin file, I include the class file, instantiate the class and call a class function. Inside the class function i call get_finance();

Comment: If the code is running as soon as the plugin is loaded then yes, it’s running before the theme function has loaded. You will need to run it inside a hook that runs after the theme has loaded.